# Terraform base64encoded with interpolation

Tags: terraform

I've been going through a long overdue task of correcting the issues found in our terraform config via `tflint`.

**Side note**: before upgrading to terraform >0.12 I never ran the `terraform 0.12upgrade` command to auto update the changes in our .tf files and have been using backward compatibility but now would like to sort it.

I have the following terraform resource:

```
resource "kubernetes_secret" "flux-infra-gcr-credentials" {
  metadata {
    name      = "flux-infra-gcr-credentials"
    namespace = "flux-system"
  }

  data = {
    ".dockerconfigjson" = jsonencode({
      auths = {
        "https://europe-west2-docker.pkg.dev" = {
          auth = "${base64encode("_json_key:${google_secret_manager_secret_version.flux-infra-gcr-credentials-v1.secret_data}")}"
        }
      }
    })
  }
```

and it flagged the following warning in `tflint`:

> Warning: Interpolation-only expressions are deprecated in Terraform v0.12.14 (terraform_deprecated_interpolation)
> on k8s_secrets.tf line 114:
> 114:           auth = "${base64encode("_json_key:${google_secret_manager_secret_version.flux-infra-gcr-credentials-v1.secret_data}")}"

Reference: https://github.com/terraform-linters/tflint-ruleset-terraform/blob/v0.2.1/docs/rules/terraform_deprecated_interpolation.md

So I followed the link and removed the `${}` from both the `base64encode` function and the `google_secret_manager_version` resource as suggested. However, a `terraform plan` suggests the value would now change, which I wouldn't expect.

What should be the correct syntax now for this?

Comment: How about `base64encode("_json_key:${google_secret_manager_secret_version.flux-infra-gcr-credentials-v1.secret_data}")`?

Comment: @MarkoE tflint still brings up the warning about the interpolation on google_secret_manager_secret_version I'm afraid

Comment: Then that would be an issue in this tflint tool you are using as @MarkoE comment removes the interpolation-only expression on that line of the config.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You saw a change because you removed too many `${` `}` markers.

The outermost expression is a string template which consists entirely of a template interpolation, which is what's meant by an "interpolation-only expression" in this warning:

```
"${base64encode(/*...*/)}"
```

The string template punctuation here is adding no additional information, and so the warning is encouraging you to replace it with just a direct call to the function:

```
base64encode(/*...*/)
```

From what you've described in your question, it sounds like you also tried to do the same thing with the interpolation sequence inside the argument to `base64encode`:

```
"_json_key:${google_secret_manager_secret_version.flux-infra-gcr-credentials-v1.secret_data}"
```

*This* string template starts with a literal part `_json_key:`, followed by an interpolation sequence. Therefore this is not an "interpolation-only expression", but rather just a normal string template with an interpolation sequence in it.

If you remove the `${` and `}` from this one then you change the meaning of the expression:

```
"_json_key:google_secret_manager_secret_version.flux-infra-gcr-credentials-v1.secret_data"
```

This is now just a string literal, with no template sequences whatsoever. Although as humans we can see that the part after `_json_key:` resembles Terraform's syntax for referring to a resource, Terraform understands the remainder as just more literal characters to be included in the string.

Therefore you effectively changed the content that was being `base64encoded`: previously it was `_json_key:` followed by your real secret data, but after you changed it then it was literally the string I wrote above, with a sequence of characters that just happens to resemble a reference to a resource attribute.

To quiet this warning without changing the meaning, you should remove only the redundant outer template punctuation, and retain the *meaningful* template punctuation inside the function argument:

```
        "https://europe-west2-docker.pkg.dev" = {
          auth = base64encode("_json_key:${google_secret_manager_secret_version.flux-infra-gcr-credentials-v1.secret_data}")
        }
```